# button_to breaks styling from bootstrap 3 button tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, button-to

I had some tags like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true" href="/groups"></span> Group/Provider
       </button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd" aria-hidden="true"></span> Billing
       </button>

<!-- etc -->
```

This worked great, the buttons were lining side by side.  Then when I went to this:  Button_to the buttons no longer arrange side by side:

```
 <%= button_to(groups_url, :class => 'btn btn-default btn-lg') do %> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>Group
 <% end %>

 <%= button_to(providers_url, :class => 'btn btn-default btn-lg') do %> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>Provider
<% end %>
```

Even though the same class was being used, any ideas?  Guessing button_to has some specific styling II would like to use the button_to url helper but I want my form to look nice...ideas suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails `button_to` actually creates a form and an input ([see the docs for example markup](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)).  Instead, I think you just want a link styled like a button, so use `link_to` and add the Bootstrap button classes:

```
link_to('Button Text', groups_url, :class => 'btn btn-default btn-large)
```

Comment: probably want this.  Can I add a span to get that glyph icon in here as well?

Comment: You can.  I ususally do this like: `link_to '<span class="glyphicons phone_alt"></span>Phones'.html_safe, phones_path, class: 'btn btn-default btn-large'`